# Almost finished with integral but hit roadblock $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan^2(x^2)}{x^2}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was evaluating the following integral

$$I:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan^2(x^2)}{x^2}\,dx$$

Here is my process. I just need some guidance to finish my work.

Solution process:

Define

$$I(t):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan^2(tx^2)}{x^2}\,dx$$

$$I’(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2\arctan(tx^2)}{t^2x^4+1}\,dx$$

$$I’(t)=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(tx^2)}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(tx^2)\,dx$$

$I.B.P$

$$I’(t)=\frac{1}{2t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan^2(tx^2)}{x^2}\,dx$$

$$I’(t)=\frac{1}{2t}I(t)$$

solving the separable ODE yields:

$$I(t)=C\sqrt{t}$$

Here is the problem! Recalling the definition of $I(t)$:

$$I(t):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan^2(tx^2)}{x^2}\,dx$$

I cannot find any initial conditions that can help me fish out the value of $C$. Is it possible? How can we do it?

Comment: Since $C=I(1)$, your parametrization seems not revealing any useful information on the integral $I$. (Note that $I(t)=I(1)\sqrt{t}$ can also be derived from the substitution $\sqrt{t}x\mapsto x$.) In this case, asymmetrizing the parametrization sometimes works.

Answer (score 7):

Integrate by parts
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(\tan^{-1}x^2)^2}{x^2}\,dx
= 4\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{1+x^4}\overset{x\to\frac1x}{dx}\\
=&\ 2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+x^4} dx
 - 4 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2\tan^{-1}x^2}{1+x^4} dx\\
 =&\ \frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt2}- 8 \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{t x^4}{(1+x^4)(1+t^4x^4)}dt \ dx\\
=&\ \frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt2}- 8 \int_0^1 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac t{t^4-1} \left(\frac{1}{1+x^4} -\frac{1}{1+t^4 x^4} \right)dx\ dt\\
 =&\ \frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt2}- \frac{4\pi}{\sqrt2} \int_0^1 \frac 1{(t+1)(t^2+1)}dt= \frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt2}-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}\ln2
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

Consider the functions

\begin{align*}
I(t) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x^2)\arctan(t^2x^2)}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x, \\
J(t) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2 \arctan(t^2 x^2)}{x^4+1} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Note that $I = I(1)$ is OP's integral. To begin with, we apply IbP to $
I(t)$ to obtain

\begin{align*}
I(t)
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \biggl( \frac{2t^2 \arctan(x^2)}{t^4 x^4 + 1} + \frac{2 \arctan(t^2 x^2)}{x^4+1} \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x
= t I'(t) + J(t). \tag{1}
\end{align*}

To evaluate $J(t)$, we invoke Feynman's trick:

\begin{align*}
J'(t)
&= 4t \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^4+1) (t^4 x^4+1)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{4t}{1-t^4} \biggl( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4+1} \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^4 x^2}{t^4 x^4+1} \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{2t(1-t)}{1-t^4}.
\end{align*}

This and $J(0) = 0$ together gives

\begin{align*}
J(t)
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{2u(1-u)}{1-u^4} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \log (t^2+1) - \log (t+1) + \arctan t \right). \tag{2}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, plugging $(2)$ to $(1)$ and invoking the method of integrating factor, the equation $(1)$ simplifies to

$$ \left( - \frac{I(t)}{t} \right)' = \frac{J(t)}{t^2} \tag{3} $$

To facilitate this equation, note that $I(\infty) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x^2)\arctan(\infty)}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$ is finite. So by integrating both sides of $(3)$ from $1$ to $\infty$, we end up with

\begin{align*}
I(1)
= \left[ - \frac{I(t)}{t} \right]_{1}^{\infty}
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{J(t)}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \left( J(1) + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{J'(t)}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t \right) \tag{IbP} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \log 2 \right) \\
&\approx 1.949646
\end{align*}

---

*Addendum.* For fun, I included both a numerical and analytic verification of this equality using Mathematica:

[image: Verification]

Answer (score 3):

Instead, apply integration by parts first. Let $u=\arctan^2(x^2)$ and $dv=\frac{dx}{x^2}$

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan^2(x^2)}{x^2}dx=4\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan(x^2)}{1+x^4}dx$$

Here we can define $I(t)$ and apply Feynman's trick much more easily. We can evaluate $I'$ using partial fractions
$$I(t)=4\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan(t^2x^2)}{1+x^4}dx,\space I(0)=0$$
$$I'(t)=8\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+t^4x^4)(1+x^4)}dx$$$$=\frac{8t^4}{t^4-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{1+t^4x^4}dx-\frac{8}{t^4-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}dx$$$$=\frac{8t}{t^4-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}dx-\frac{8}{t^4-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}dx$$$$=\frac{8t-8}{t^4-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}dx=\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt2(1+t)(1+t^2)}$$
We can integrate the expression using partial fractions
$$I(t)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt2}\int\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}-\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1}{1+t}\right)dt$$$$=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt2}\left(\arctan t-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+t^2)+\ln(1+t)\right)+I(0)$$
$$=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt2}\left(\arctan t-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+t^2)+\ln(1+t)\right)$$
Evaluate at $t=1$
$$I=I(1)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln2+\ln2\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2$$
This is the answer

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan^2 x^2}{x^2} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} y^2 \csc(2y) \sqrt{\tan y} \, dy \tag1 \\
&= 2 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} y \sqrt{\cot y} \, dy \tag2 \\
&= 2 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \left(\frac\pi2-z\right) \sqrt{\tan z} \, dz \tag3 \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt2} - 2 \left(\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt2}+\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}\ln2\right) = \boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt2}-\frac\pi{\sqrt2}\ln2}
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ Substitute $x=\sqrt{\tan y}$
- $(2)$ Integrate by parts
- $(3)$ Substitute $y=\dfrac\pi2-z$
- $(4)$ See these AoPS posts (found with [ApproachZero](https://www.approach0.xyz/search/)):
  [$\displaystyle\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2}\sqrt{\tan x}\,dx$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2439831p20208247) $\quad$ [$\displaystyle\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2}x\sqrt{\tan x}\,dx$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1893181p12925429)